# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 40: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, file-io, io, output

I'm trying to save concrete content of the dictionary to a file but when I try to write it, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "P4.py", line 83, in <module>
    outfile.write(u"{}\t{}\n".format(keyword, str(tagSugerido)).encode("utf-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 40: ordinal not in range(128)
```

And here is the code:

```
from collections import Counter

with open("corpus.txt") as inf:
    wordtagcount = Counter(line.decode("latin_1").rstrip() for line in inf)

with open("lexic.txt", "w") as outf:
    outf.write('Palabra\tTag\tApariciones\n'.encode("utf-8"))
    for word,count in wordtagcount.iteritems():
        outf.write(u"{}\t{}\n".format(word, count).encode("utf-8"))
"""
2) TAGGING USING THE MODEL
Dados los ficheros de test, para cada palabra, asignarle el tag mas
probable segun el modelo. Guardar el resultado en ficheros que tengan
este formato para cada linea: Palabra  Prediccion
"""
file=open("lexic.txt", "r") # abrimos el fichero lexic (nuestro modelo) (probar con este)
data=file.readlines()
file.close()
diccionario = {}

"""
In this portion of code we iterate the lines of the .txt document and we create a dictionary with a word as a key and a List as a value
Key: word
Value: List ([tag, #ocurrencesWithTheTag])
"""
for linea in data:
    aux = linea.decode('latin_1').encode('utf-8')
    sintagma = aux.split('\t')  # Here we separate the String in a list: [word, tag, ocurrences], word=sintagma[0], tag=sintagma[1], ocurrences=sintagma[2]
    if (sintagma[0] != "Palabra" and sintagma[1] != "Tag"): #We are not interested in the first line of the file, this is the filter
        if (diccionario.has_key(sintagma[0])): #Here we check if the word was included before in the dictionary
            aux_list = diccionario.get(sintagma[0]) #We know the name already exists in the dic, so we create a List for every value
            aux_list.append([sintagma[1], sintagma[2]]) #We add to the list the tag and th ocurrences for this concrete word
            diccionario.update({sintagma[0]:aux_list}) #Update the value with the new list (new list = previous list + new appended element to the list)
        else: #If in the dic do not exist the key, que add the values to the empty list (no need to append)
            aux_list_else = ([sintagma[1],sintagma[2]])
            diccionario.update({sintagma[0]:aux_list_else})

"""
Here we create a new dictionary based on the dictionary created before, in this new dictionary (diccionario2) we want to keep the next
information:
Key: word
Value: List ([suggestedTag, #ocurrencesOfTheWordInTheDocument, probability])

For retrieve the information from diccionario, we have to keep in mind:

In case we have more than 1 Tag associated to a word (keyword ), we access to the first tag with keyword[0], and for ocurrencesWithTheTag with keyword[1],
from the second case and forward, we access to the information by this way:

diccionario.get(keyword)[2][0] -> with this we access to the second tag
diccionario.get(keyword)[2][1] -> with this we access to the second ocurrencesWithTheTag
diccionario.get(keyword)[3][0] -> with this we access to the third tag
...
..
.
etc.
"""
diccionario2 = dict.fromkeys(diccionario.keys())#We create a dictionary with the keys from diccionario and we set all the values to None
with open("estimation.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for keyword in diccionario:
        tagSugerido = unicode(diccionario.get(keyword[0]).decode('utf-8')) #tagSugerido is the tag with more ocurrences for a concrete keyword
        maximo = float(diccionario.get(keyword)[1]) #maximo is a variable for the maximum number of ocurrences in a keyword
        if ((len(diccionario.get(keyword))) > 2): #in case we have > 2 tags for a concrete word
            suma = float(diccionario.get(keyword)[1])
            for i in range (2, len(diccionario.get(keyword))):
                suma += float(diccionario.get(keyword)[i][1])
                if (diccionario.get(keyword)[i][1] > maximo):
                    tagSugerido = unicode(diccionario.get(keyword)[i][0]).decode('utf-8'))
                    maximo = float(diccionario.get(keyword)[i][1])
            probabilidad = float(maximo/suma);
            diccionario2.update({keyword:([tagSugerido, suma, probabilidad])})

        else:
            diccionario2.update({keyword:([diccionario.get(keyword)[0],diccionario.get(keyword)[1], 1])})

        outfile.write(u"{}\t{}\n".format(keyword, tagSugerido).encode("utf-8"))
```

The desired output will look like this:

```
keyword(String)  tagSugerido(String):
Hello    NC
Friend   N
Run      V
...etc
```

The conflictive line is:

```
outfile.write(u"{}\t{}\n".format(keyword, str(tagSugerido)).encode("utf-8"))
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like zmo suggested:

```
outfile.write(u"{}\t{}\n".format(keyword, str(tagSugerido)).encode("utf-8"))
```

should be:

```
outfile.write(u"{}\t{}\n".format(keyword, tagSugerido.encode("utf-8")))
```

**A note on unicode in Python 2**

Your software should only work with unicode strings internally, converting to a particular encoding on output.

Do prevent from making the same error over and over again you should make sure you understood the difference between **ascii** and **utf-8** encodings and also between **str** and **unicode** objects in Python.

**The difference between ASCII and UTF-8 encoding:**

Ascii needs just one byte to represent all possible characters in the ascii charset/encoding. UTF-8 needs up to four bytes to represent the complete  charset.

```
ascii (default)
1    If the code point is < 128, each byte is the same as the value of the code point.
2    If the code point is 128 or greater, the Unicode string can’t be represented in this encoding. (Python raises a UnicodeEncodeError exception in this case.)

utf-8 (unicode transformation format)
1    If the code point is <128, it’s represented by the corresponding byte value.
2    If the code point is between 128 and 0x7ff, it’s turned into two byte values between 128 and 255.
3    Code points >0x7ff are turned into three- or four-byte sequences, where each byte of the sequence is between 128 and 255.
```

**The difference between str and unicode objects:**

You can say that str is baiscally a byte string and unicode is a unicode string. Both can have a different encoding like ascii or utf-8.

```
str vs. unicode
1   str     = byte string (8-bit) - uses \x and two digits
2   unicode = unicode string      - uses \u and four digits
3   basestring
        /\
       /  \
    str    unicode
```

If you follow some simple rules you should go fine with handling str/unicode objects in different encodings like ascii or utf-8 or whatever encoding you have to use:

```
Rules
1    encode(): Gets you from Unicode -> bytes
     encode([encoding], [errors='strict']), returns an 8-bit string version of the Unicode string,
2    decode(): Gets you from bytes -> Unicode
     decode([encoding], [errors]) method that interprets the 8-bit string using the given encoding
3    codecs.open(encoding=”utf-8″): Read and write files directly to/from Unicode (you can use any encoding, not just utf-8, but utf-8 is most common).
4    u”: Makes your string literals into Unicode objects rather than byte sequences.
5    unicode(string[, encoding, errors])
```

**Warning: Don’t use encode() on bytes or decode() on Unicode objects**

**And again: Software should only work with Unicode strings internally, converting to a particular encoding on output.**

Answer (score 2):

As you're not giving a simple concise code to illustrate your question, I'll just give you a general advice on what should be the error:

If you're getting a decode error, it's that `tagSugerido` is read as ASCII and not as Unicode. To fix that, you should do:

```
tagSugerido = unicode(diccionario.get(keyword[0]).decode('utf-8'))
```

to store it as an unicode.

Then you're likely to get an encode error at the `write()` stage, and you should fix your write the following way:

```
outfile.write(u"{}\t{}\n".format(keyword, str(tagSugerido)).encode("utf-8"))
```

should be:

```
outfile.write(u"{}\t{}\n".format(keyword, tagSugerido.encode("utf-8")))
```

I litterally answered a very similar question [moments ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28852321/python-unicodedecodeerror-when-writing-german-letters/28852466#28852466). And when working with unicode strings, ***switch to python3***, it'll make your life easier!

If you cannot switch to python3 just yet, you can make your python2 behave like it is almost python3, using the [python-future](http://python-future.org/imports.html) import statement:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
```

---

N.B.: instead of doing:

```
file=open("lexic.txt", "r") # abrimos el fichero lexic (nuestro modelo) (probar con este)
data=file.readlines()
file.close()
```

which will fail to close properly the file descriptor upon failure during readlines, you should better do:

```
with open("lexic.txt", "r") as f:
    data=f.readlines()
```

which will take care of always closing the file even upon failure.

N.B.2: Avoid using *file* as this is a python type you're shadowing, but use `f` or `lexic_file`…

Comment: Thanks for your help, I updated the code with your tips but now I'm getting this error: 
`File "P4.py", line 75
  outfile.write(u"{}\t{}\n".format(keyword, tagSugerido.encode("utf-8")))                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @Gerard doesn't give me invalid syntax. Maybe you have something wrong on another line?

Comment: @gerard please make a [SSCCE](http://ssce.org), giving an error within a comment (in a way where the it's impossible to know what character the `^` is pointing), and a code that parses two files we don't have is not helping. Look at my other answer to show how you can make the error happen in a few lines with a couple of one line files.

Comment: and also, @Gerard, consider switching to python3, as all your unicode issues will disappear. It's definitely worth the few changes that shall be made to make your code compatible!

Comment: well, if you learn correctly the advantages of going to python 3, and you prove to your teacher that teaching you outdated tools is non-sense, (s)he can only accept your code. And if you make your code compatible with both python2 and python3 using futures or the `six` package, then you'll have hacked his  poor assignment choice!

Comment: *Here's a personal fact: I have boycotted a visual basic course I had back in college, by giving a fully detailed argumentation why I won't loose a second of my time working on such a stupid language, as I got more important/interesting things to learn instead. She agreed to leave me skip the whole course, only doing the final exam, I passed it with the best mark ;-)*

Comment: @zmo haha nice story bro, but the professor hates Python 3 (I don't know why) and if the code is not strictly in Python 2.X --> Fail.

Comment: well, then you can still use futures or [six](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six/1.9.0), which definitely are python2!