# Parsing UTF-8 XML-Files with Python

Tags: python, unicode, lxml

i've got an XML-File with contains some german umlauts. My goal is to read in the file and store the results into a database. For testing I got two different files. The first is according to chardet *UTF-8-SIG* the other one is *UTF-8*.

Preprocessing the data is done by `unicode(field[0])` after reading the file with lxml

Parsing the first file works fine, but processing the other results in an encoding error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position: ordinal not in range(128)

For example such string can be u'Zubeh\xf6r' (`print(field[0]`).

Using `print (field[0].encode("utf-8"))` results in the right string, but the type is `str` instead of `unicode`

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28852321/python-unicodedecodeerror-when-writing-german-letters

Comment: thanks. I've updated the question

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
from lxml import etree
parser=etree.HTMLParser(encoding='utf-8')
```

when you read the data with lxml.

Comment: encoding is correct, but it's still "str" as type instead of "unicode"

Comment: When you 'encode' a Unicode string you'll get 'str'. What are you trying to do exactly, if you post some code, I can help you better.

Comment: I'm trying to get data from a xml-file and store it to an utf8 database via django-orm mapper.