# German Umlaute in CSV as literals

Tags: python, csv, unicode, utf-8

I have a csv that contains a field with German Umlaute (ä,ö,ü) as literals such like this:

`b'Beitr\xc3\xa4ge'`

I've tried to read this **.csv** and just print the original words (`Beiträge`), but no matter what I do, I only seem to get `b'Beitr\xc3\xa4ge'` back.
I've tried following all sorts of advice on how to convert to and from Unicode, I've tried both Python 2.7 and 3, but I'm stumped.

What should I do?

Comment: similar question asked in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28852321/python-unicodedecodeerror-when-writing-german-letters. you may get some help.

Comment: I assume you read the `CSV`in Binary Mode using `'rb`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the decode funtion:

```
b'Beitr\xc3\xa4ge'.decode('utf-8')
```

returns

```
Beiträge
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to use these "Umlaute" as well. To solve that problem I write in every first line of my python modules

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
```

Works fine for me in Python 3.6 
If I than type s.th. like

```
print("Beträge")
```

The output in the console is "Beträge"